# How do you pop the giant bubble in the Golden Apple Archipelago?

Tags: genshin-impact

[image]

Tried running around it trying to find some puzzle mechanism. There's a set of 3 lasers converging onto a single crystal at one part but it doesn't seem like you can interact with it.  Is there a way to pop the bubble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That whole area (Golden Apple Archipelago) is part of the current event for June 2021. The event was released in four parts coming out at different points in time. Each part progresses a bit of the Event quest along with adding some side content.

As of now the event is still running, but all parts have been released. To open that *'bubble'* you must progress the event quest line, up to the point you're asked to unseal that area through interacting with the pillars you've mentioned.

It's worth noting that this part of the quest wasn't available at the time the question was asked.